What is the correct way to handle models and entities in clean architecture?
So I'm trying to set up all the basics for a new .NET application. It's a Blazor app, to be created with clean architecture and code-first EF Core.
In my domain layer I defined some entities which will be used be EF Core to generate the database. And in the presentation/WebUI layer I created a folder for models that I can give to the razor files. The original idea was to map directly from the entities to the models when I'm retrieving the data.
When creating the interfaces for my services in the application layer I realized that the application layer is not supposed to have access to the presentation layer. Therefore I cannot have an interface like Task<SomeModel> GetSomeModelByIdAsync(int id);. I would have to return the entity but I don't want that sent all the way out to the outer layer right?
What would be the correct way of handling this. Do I move my models to the application layer, or do I create DTOs that the presentation layer can map to the models? It's only a hobby project so I'm fine by taking my time and getting things better than they have to be. Yes I'm probably overthinking it, what fun would it be otherwise?

Yeah in most applications i have seen one would introduce a dto because usally what the ef entity provides and what is allowed to be seen in the ui are different shoes.

Every layer should have contract objects, to deal with the other layer ... you can take a look on my personal project Movie Quotes on GitHub to see how I handle that I use clean architecture + CQRS I believe it will help you

Usually application layer defines "what is it about", meaning definition of models that drive the app. So it is perfectly normal to have models in app layer and just let data layer to handle CRUD operations for those models (data layer is not about the data itself, but rather handling it).

You can't make decisions regarding what to retrieve without considering the size of the entities. You're already assuming that surfacing any entity is "too much" and you must resort to "DTO's"; creating an extra layer of abstraction for no good reason.

All of this, even using something like "clean architecture", can't be decided without intimate knowledge of functional and non-functional requirements. Obviously, you can't provide all of that. Which means that as a question this will never get beyond the "opinion-based" stage.

If you want to apply Clean Design principles you should design your core domain entities based on your application requirements.
Considering the Weather forecast as a simple example, you could define it like this.
Note:

I've created objects to represent temperature and the Id.  Using a Guid and a decimal is classic Primitive Obsession where you're letting your datastore dictate your application design.

I use a lot of read only objects to prevent mutation.  Inadvertent mutation is the cause of many bugs.


public sealed record DmoWeatherForecast
{
    public WeatherForecastId WeatherForecastId { get; init; } = WeatherForecastId.NewEntity;
    public DateOnly Date { get; init; }
    public Temperature Temperature { get; set; } = new(0);
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}

Where WeatherForecastId is:
public readonly record struct WeatherForecastId
{
    public Guid Value { get; init; }
    public object KeyValue => this.Value;

    public WeatherForecastId(Guid value)
        => this.Value = value;

    public static WeatherForecastId NewEntity
        => new(Guid.Empty);
}

And Temperature is:
public record Temperature
{
    public decimal TemperatureC { get; init; }
    public decimal TemperatureF => 32 + (this.TemperatureC / 0.5556m);

    public Temperature() { }

    public Temperature(decimal temperature)
    {
        this.TemperatureC = temperature;
    }
}

In the infrastructure layer we need to fall back on primitives to fit with the data store:
public sealed record DboWeatherForecast
{
    [Key] public Guid WeatherForecastID { get; init; } = Guid.Empty;
    public DateTime Date { get; init; }
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}

You can use various options to do the mapping. I've created my own mapper:
public sealed class DboWeatherForecastMap : IDboEntityMap<DboWeatherForecast, DmoWeatherForecast>
{
    public DmoWeatherForecast MapTo(DboWeatherForecast item)
        => Map(item);

    public DboWeatherForecast MapTo(DmoWeatherForecast item)
        => Map(item);

    public static DmoWeatherForecast Map(DboWeatherForecast item)
        => new()
        {
            WeatherForecastId = new(item.WeatherForecastID),
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(item.Date),
            Temperature = new(item.Temperature),
            Summary = item.Summary
        };

    public static DboWeatherForecast Map(DmoWeatherForecast item)
        => new()
        {
            WeatherForecastID = item.WeatherForecastId.Value,
            Date = item.Date.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
            Temperature = item.Temperature.TemperatureC,
            Summary = item.Summary
        };
}

You can see a full implementation here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo
There's also an Invoice implementation to demonstrate how to deal with complex entities.
This approach is more complex that using a simple class WeatherForecast object defined in the core domain, whose design is driven by the datastore.  There's nothing wrong in using this approach in a simple application.
Note: I use the term Core Domain to represent what many people call the Domain and Application layers.  The Domain Domain doesn't work!
